# Running command through Terminal working fine but using shell_exec not - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shell, plugins

I'm writing a PHP script to scrape external website products. The external website uses JavaScript to render product lists that's why my PHP script was not working to scrape those products.

So, I searched for another solution and found JavaScript libraries like **PhantomJS** and **CasperJS**.

I've done all my work on my local server but when I'm unable to run my code on Linux.

**Here is what I tried through cPanel terminal:**

```
export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
```

And

```
/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/casperjs/bin/casperjs /home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/assets/js/ScrapeCategoryProducts.js
```

I got the expected result **but** when I tried the same in my PHP code using `shell_exec`, it didn't work. Here is the PHP file code.

```
shell_exec('export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs');
```

And

```
exec('/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/casperjs/bin/casperjs /home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/assets/js/ScrapeCategoryProducts.js');
```

**NOTE:** I also tried adding **2>&1** in the script and I double-checked that the `shell_exec` command is enabled.

Also, tried using putenv but it didn't work.

```
putenv("CASPERJS_EXECUTABLE=".SC_PLUGIN_DIR.'includes/casperjs/bin/casperjs');
```

*Let me if you need more detail.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The both commands you execute in `shell_exec(...)` and in `exec(...)` do not share the same environment. Different shells are started which is why the `export` of the first call is without effect in the second call. Combine both by either concatenating them with a semicolon.

Comment: Apart from that you need to make sure the http server process has read and execution permission on all folders leading up the those commands.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: ```shell_exec('export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs; /home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/casperjs/bin/casperjs /home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/assets/js/ScrapeCategoryProducts.js 2>&1');```

I tried above and got this error ```/home/saadatas/public_html/wp-content/plugins/product-scraper/includes/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs() 8 0x7f9b30bdf0e5 [0x7f9b30bdf0e5] PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at and file a bug report.```

Comment: OK, so your logic tries to execute the script how, but that fails. I cannot say anything about that is, obviously. Apart from that: why do you export an environment variable if you then still use absolute path in your actual command? And what does that bug report say? What output do you get from the `exec` command? I mean when you use the second, optional parameter you can hand over?

Comment: Actually, I've shared hosting and don't have permission to add the env variable permanently from the env variable settings. So, that's why I'm using the absolute path.

Sorry, I didn't get your 2nd question.

Comment: I did say nothing about permanently adding an environment variable. You explicitly set an environment variable with your first command (''export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE= .....`). Why do you do that if you don't use it afterwards?

Comment: About the output of the `exec(...)` command: the documentation of that command demonstrates how you can hand over a second, optional argument. Which you can use to learn the output of the command you try to execute. Since you redirect the commands stderr stream to the stdout stream (`... 2>&1`) that means you would get back _all_ output generated by that command. That certainly would be very helpful to know. So what is it?

Comment: So, actually, I'm using CasperJS and PhantomJS is its dependency. Thant's why I need to use PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE as env. variable. Otherwise, CasperJS won't work.

Comment: Hm, the documentation and the examples in there do not require that variable. I would expect you could simply use relative paths instead which would make everything much easier to read. But anyway, that is not the issue here.

Comment: Now, the command running through the PHP code but when the script starts, PhantomJS crashes right away. Any idea?

Remember the same thing working fine from cPanel terminal.

Comment: Sorry, since there is no further data I cannot assist with a new idea. Did you capture the command output? What does it say?